# How to do dynamic objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to define a dynamic object type in TypeScript?
In the following example, I would like to define a type for "My Complex Type" by saying:

Objects of type "My Complex Type" are objects having "any number of properties" but the values of those properties must be of type IValue.

```
// value interface
interface IValue {
    prop:string
}

// My Complex Type
myType = {
    field1:IValue
    field2:IValue
    .
    .
    .
    fieldN:IValue
}

// Using My Complex Type 

interface SomeType {
    prop:My Complex Type
}
```

Comment: can you not create an object which has a map of `string->IValue`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, that kind of behavior can be achieved, but in slightly different way. You just need to use typescript interface, like:

```
interface IValue {
    prop: string
}

interface MyType {
    [name: string]: IValue;
}
```

that will be used for example like:

```
var t: MyType = {};
t['field1'] = { prop: null };
t['field2'] = new DifferentType(); // compile-time error
...
var val = t['field1'];
val.prop = 'my prop value';
```

You don't have to create typescript class, Everything you need is a regular javascript object ( in that case {} ) and make it implement interface MyType, so it behaves like dictionary and provide you with compile-time type safety.

Comment: **Thank You** You just saved me so much agony and grief trying to get redux-form working in TypeScript!