# How to defined interface for object with known and unknown property name

Tags: typescript

Here is an object I would love to define an interface for,

```
{
  date: '2000-10-01',
  foo: 10,
  bar: 11,
  baz: 12
}
```

The only thing I know is `date` property is always there but I do not know what other properties will be?

```
interface IProperty {
  date: string
  [option: string]: number
}
```

Does not seem to work in this case, TS complains that

> string is not assignable to string index type number.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840596/how-to-do-dynamic-objects-in-typescript ?

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem.

Comment: try with it, Its complete dynamic so you can access date as well dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original interface, you state that the interface will contain string indexes, and return a number - but your `date` property doesn't adhere to this, which means your interface contradicts itself.

You'll need to be honest about the fact you can get a number, or a string (in one specific case)...

```
interface IProperty {
  date: string
  [option: string]: string | number;
}
```