# Add Partially Known Typescript Properties to Any

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Let's say I have a variable:

```
var myVariable; // type === any
```

And I know for sure that there are some properties on that object that I would like strongly typed, but I don't know all of them.

Let's say I know there is a single property called "MyProperty" which is a number. I want to use it like this:

```
myVariable.MyProperty += 10; // MyProperty should be a number, obviously
```

What I've tried doing is this:

```
var myVariable: { MyProperty: number }; // type === { MyProperty: number }
```

But that causes *other* properties being referenced on `myVariable` to not compile:

```
myVariable.SomeOtherProperty = 'whatever'; // typescript error! That property doesn't exist :(
```

Is there any syntax that will give me my desired behavior? Currently using Typescript 2.1.5 but the answer could be for any version.

Also, I'd like to also not resort to using string indexes on the variable (`myVariable['SomeOtherProperty']`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to defined interface for object with known and unknown property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559319/how-to-defined-interface-for-object-with-known-and-unknown-property-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: For the following to work without errors, you need to upgrade to at least [TypeScript 2.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#dotted-property-for-types-with-string-index-signatures).

You're probably going to want to add an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) to your type, like this:

```
var myVariable: { MyProperty: number; [k: string]: any };
myVariable = { MyProperty: 10 }; // okay
myVariable.MyProperty = "hello"; // error, known to be a number
myVariable.SomeOtherProperty = 20; // okay, any
myVariable.YetAnotherProperty = "hello"; // also okay, any
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I thought that might work but unfortunately it gives me this error: `Property 'SomeOtherProperty' does not exist on type '{ [k: string]: any; MyProperty: number; }'.`. It would work if I access the property via index: `myVariable['SomeOtherProperty']` but I don't want to change the existing code to work like that :(

Comment: Ah, yes.  Dotted notation for index signatures was added in TypeScript 2.2.  Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Welp, you've got it exactly, just tested it out w/ 2.2+. I'm using typescript 2.1.5 for this project -- ha.